# How can I connect laptop to my Epson Stylus Office BX600FW printer

Tags: drivers, printing

Printer worked perfectly prior to upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04. I can scan and save files.
Have tried: disconnecting/reconnecting printer, re-installed printer as new device, installed new Driver-Current-Epson stylus Office BX600FW-CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.10-pre2- Connection: usb:/EPSON/Stylus%20Office%20BX600FW?serial=4B5033593031303500&interface=1
States - Printer Ready Rendering complete. But when I try to print, I get this: In use-printing page 1 1,22%. So I cancel the print job and I'm back at Printer ready. I just go round in a circle.
Prior to installing new Driver I had the message Idle or In use printing page 1 1,22%. I've cancelled all print jobs in queue. And tried restarting the LT. I have absolutely no idea what to do!
I am a novice(don't understand the jargon) and really am useless - can somebody help me - I'll need an idiots guide from step1-?.

I use a Laptop HP Pavilion dm4 - although Windows(7 or 8)is installed it's on a separate partition, that I never use.

If you need any further info, will be happy to supply. Thank you in advance for you time and patience!

Comment: Why not install proproetary Epson drivers instead of gutenprint?

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's not the recommended driver.

http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Epson/Epson-Stylus_Office_BX300F

Answer (score 0):

You can download and install Epson proprietary printer and scanner drivers from [Epson Drivers Site](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX)

Enter `BX600` in the Search field and download deb files for your system (amd64 or i386).